# How can I resolve this 'has no attribute' error in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, object, inheritance

I tried to make a class Parent and a subclass called Child. After that I     passed the arguments of child to parent using the constructor init but this error keeps getting thrown. How can I fix this? By the way if I assign the values in the subclass by doing Parent.name=name, etc it works fine. But how can I do this using a constructor?

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, name, color):
        print("Parent Constructor called")
        self.firstname=name
        self.eyecolor=color

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, name, color, toys):
        print("Child Constructor called")
        Parent.__init__(self,name,color)
        self.toys=toys

robert_langdon=Child("Holmes", "brown", 5)
print(robert_langdon.name)
print(robert_langdon.toys)
```

[image: Snapshot of the error thrown]

Comment: Shouldn't you be looking for robert_langdon.firstname?

Comment: Exactly that solved it! Thanks a lot!! I was almost gonna go insane looking for an answer!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive this should work (I've used `super` so as not to refer to the base class explicitly, and you were also looking for the wrong attribute (should be `firstname` not `name`)):

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, name, color):
        print("Parent Constructor called")
        self.firstname=name
        self.eyecolor=color

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, name, color, toys):
        print("Child constructor called")
        super(Child,self).__init__(name,color)
        self.toys=toys

robert_langdon=Child("Holmes", "brown", 5)
print(robert_langdon.firstname)
print(robert_langdon.toys)
```